# How can i filter fast the huge csv file based on list of ids from another file using bash?

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I have 2 csv files.
The first one is just a list of IDs (around 300k rows). Lest call it ids.csv

```
id
1
3
7
...
```

The second one is list of objects with id (around 2 milions rows). Lets call it data.csv

```
id,date,state
1,2022-01-01,true
4,2022-01-03,false
...
```

I would like to build the 3rd csv file with rows from data.csv which having IDs from ids.csv. It is not necessary that all of IDs from ids.csv will be present in data.csv.

I tried something like this:

```
while IFS=, read -r line
do
    awk -F',' -v id='$line' '$1==id' data.csv >> out.csv
done < ids.csv
```

It is working, but executions takes something like forever. I tried to split it for several streams, but the script is working slow by itself so it was not helping mutch.

Can you suggest me better or more optimal way how to filter that data.csv faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the most common answer on this forum in one way or another:

```
awk -F',' 'NR==FNR{ids[$1]; next} $1 in ids' ids.csv data.csv > out.csv
```

That will be an order of magnitude faster than your existing script.

Regarding why your original script is slow, see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: Thanks so much! That oneliner just nailed the case in a second!

Answer (score 1):

Using `csvgrep` from the handy [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) bundle of utilities:

```bash
$ csvgrep -c id -f ids.csv data.csv
id,date,state
1,2022-01-01,true
```

`-f filename` is like plain `grep`'s `-f` argument; if any of the lines in it are a match for the given column name, that record is printed.

Comment: I don't know csvkit; will the IDs in ids.csv be treated as regex? +1

Comment: @Fravadona No, literal strings.

Answer (score 0):

you can rework the standard de-duping code for this :

```
 {m,g}awk 'NR==FNR ?!--__[$_]:__[$!_]' FS=',' ids.csv data.csv
 or
 {m,g}awk -F',' '(_=FNR==NR)<(__[$!_]+=_)' ids.csv data.csv

 1  id,date,state
 2  1,2022-01-01,true
```